# I can't see my transformation files (PDI) in Pentaho user console

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-cde, pentaho-data-integration

I have csv files in the local file system that contain output results of a program. I want to use Pentaho CDE to visualize those data in graphs (Pie charts ...)

I can do that if I upload my csv files directly as a datasource. But I would like to read from my file in real time as data come.

I saw that I have to use PDI and I created a transformation from the input csv file to an output file. I can visualize the output.
[image]

I saved the transformation file .ktr in pentaho-solutions directory But I can't see it in Pentaho user Console. I think that I have to use a kettle over kettleTransFromFile but I can't see my transformation file to load it ! I refreshed the cache but still can't see it ...

Am I doing this wrong ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: How your transformation is being executed?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Thank you for your response. I'm new to Pentaho. I made my transformation with spoon and It's running. Did I get this wrong ?

Comment: Perfect. Now you need to schedule it to run at regular intervals. You can do it via comand line utility PAN. and if you have an enterprise license then i can tell you one more solution.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava I got my transformation running with Pan and It ended successfully but I still can't find it in the user Console to use it for my CDE. Am I missing another step ?

Comment: PS : I just run the command : ./pan.sh /file:"myTransformation.ktr"

Comment: Use the filesystem. Put that in the same directory of your dashboard or a subfolder and restart CDE then Use the filepicker to select the ktr. In the query property, use the name of the step you want to extract.

Comment: I'm trying to do that but I can't see my dashboard in the file system actually. I think Pentaho User Console is simulating it's own file system...

Comment: I've put that in "../../plugin-samples/cda/cdafiles" where there is "sample-trans.ktr" that I can see in the user console but I still can't see my file